# android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" not functioning as expected.

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-linearlayout

I'm attempting to alighn my assist_update_btn with the bottom of the screen however it does not seem to do so. For some reason it's sitting just below the TextView and isn't aligning with the bottom of the screen for some reason.

Any input is greatly appreciated.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- LinearLayout allows border to expand to entire screen -->
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/background"
android:orientation="vertical" >
>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/apn_app_text_cta2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:layout_marginTop="30sp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="30sp"
                android:layout_marginRight="30sp"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:text="@string/apn_app_text_cta2"/>


            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/assist_update_btn"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/apn_app_text_cta2"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:src="@drawable/btn_next_inactivei" />

        </RelativeLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Comment: U want both your textview and imageview at the bottom of layout and imageview below the textview??Is that you want??

Answer (score 1):

Try the below code in layout.Added `android:fillViewport="true"` in `ScrollView` and
removed  `android:layout_below="@+id/apn_app_text_cta2"` from `ImageView`

```
<!-- LinearLayout allows border to expand to entire screen -->
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:fillViewport="true"

 >


        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/apn_app_text_cta2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:layout_marginTop="30sp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="30sp"
                android:layout_marginRight="30sp"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:text="@string/apn_app_text_cta2"/>


            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/assist_update_btn"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:src="@drawable/btn_next_inactivei"/>

        </RelativeLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

This should work

Answer (score 0):

This is because of this line

```
android:layout_below="@+id/apn_app_text_cta2"
```

remove it and you should get the expected results. That line is conflicting with aligning it with the bottom of its parent.

Comment: It still does not align with the bottom of the screen

Comment: It's laid over the text (and appears to aligned with the bottom of it)

Comment: Ah, I see. Combine this answer with jansel's answer and it will work.

Comment: How can I actually get it to appear beneath apn_app_text_cta2 then?

Comment: What do you mean? I thought you wanted it at the bottom of the screen?

Answer (score 0):

this occurs because ScrollView dont wrap entire screen set `android:fillViewport="true"` to scrollview and also remove `android:layout_below="@+id/apn_app_text_cta2"` from `ImageView` to achieve that.

Comment: How can I actually get it to appear beneath apn_app_text_cta2 then?

Comment: Just adding `android:fillViewport="true"` to your scrollview and removing `android:layout_below="@+id/apn_app_text_cta2"` from ImageView